# How to kill an "exiting" process on OS X (state = E)

Tags: mac-osx, process, kill

I have a process on my Mac OS X system which is in state E ("The process is trying to exit."):

```
% ps auwwwxc | grep -si JavaApplicationS
sbwoodside    84547   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??   E   Mon12am   0:00.00 (JavaApplicationS)
```

kill -9 84547 does nothing. Is there any special trick to get this process to exit? It's holding some ports open that I would like it to let go of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would probably be to restart. I've seen it happen once or twice before, and from memory, nothing I did could unstick it.

Comment: Apparently you are correct :-(

Answer (score 0):

I second the restart solution... 
I had zombies I could not kill as well.

Unfortunately `kill -9` is not really "the ultimate axe" on the OS X as it seems to be either filtered or flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is something I haven't encountered what is happening is kill -9 kills it the launchd restarts it. two solutions 1. Kill launchd But this means that **you won't be able to start any new process** 2. Restart system 
Long term fix. Reconfigure launchd so that it doesnt do this.
ps
The only processes I have seen that take up that high a pid are trojan horses.

Comment: I believe it was Vuze.